# Pattern suggestions to work around alternation operator limitations

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regex pattern matcher.

The complete string pattern is as follow:

```
AB123456C12
Letter A
Letter B
six digits
one letter
two digits.
```

I'm trying to match as much as possible, but partial inputs are allowed as long as the initial AB is present.
The RegEx engine is Javascript. Hoping to be fully cross-browser compatible.

I do have a pattern that works:

```
^AB([0-9]{6}[A-Z][0-9]{0,2}|[0-9]{0,6})$
```

But it only works when the arguments of the [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) are in this position. Said otherwise,

```
^AB([0-9]{0,6}|[0-9]{6}[A-Z][0-9]{0,2})$
```

doesn't work - which makes me believe that the solution may not work in some obscure browser.

So, any other way to define that pattern?

Thanks.

Edited for clarity: the followings are inputs that must be matched by the regex:

```
AB
AB123
AB123456Z
```

The followings input are to be rejected:

```
B
B123456Z12
ABC
123456
```

Comment: I don't understand how the match should happen, have you heard about non capturing groups?

Comment: What's wrong with this `^AB[0-9]{6}[A-Z][0-9]{2}$`? I think this satisfies your conditions. I don't know why you used an alternation operator.

Comment: @alfa64 I'm not using the resulting subgroups. Only the whole result.

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's what I meant by "partial inputs are allowed". AB123 is legit. See the newly added examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

```
 #  ^AB(?:(?:[0-9]{6}(?:[A-Z][0-9]{0,2})?)|[0-9]{1,5})?$

 ^                             # BOS
 AB                            # AB
 (?:                           # Optional cl-1
      (?:                           # Required cl-2
           [0-9]{6}                      # Required 6 digits
           (?:                           # Optional cl-3   
                [A-Z]                         # Required A-Z letter
                [0-9]{0,2}                    # Required 0-2 (0 means optional)
           )?                            # End cl-3
      )                             # End cl-2
   |                              # or
      [0-9]{1,5}                    # Required 1-5 digits
 )?                            # End cl-1
 $                             # EOS
```

Comment: I believe this expression has the same limitation than my original one - if the argument to the left of the OR operator is swapped with the argument to the right of it, it no longer works.

Comment: @jmr - Not true. This expression's alternations are interchangeable. Try it out. In fact, this is the _only_ expression that works for partial matches, given your requirements.

Comment: Apologies for commenting without trying. They are indeed interchangeable. Looking at it and your comment about your solution being the only valid one, can you explain why removing the optional marker on cl-1 and replacing {1,5} by {0,5} wouldn't work?

Comment: @jmr - That defeats the purpose. All partial matches are thought of as a cascading optional hierarchy. As you traverse the path there must be at least one _fixed/required_ construct. If you stay within that framework you will write consistent expressions that never fall apart no matter how much you add/subtract. In this case cl-1 has two fixed paths, where each path requires a match, _even though c1-1 is optional_.

Comment: Thank you for the original answer as well as the extra information. Answer accepted as correct. I understand that this is the application of a design pattern, but I don't fully understand it. If, by any chance, you have a reference to an article describing it, I would gladly read more on the subject. Thanks again.

Comment: @jmr - No problem. What I know comes from personal experience, not really from books. Look closely at this `a (?: b (?: c1 (?: X )? | c2 (?: X )? )? )?` , follow the paths to completion. You will see that none of the constants themselves are optional, only the nodes within the tree are. This is a typical cascade.

Answer (score 1):

This may help

```
^AB[0-9]{6}[A-Z][0-9]{2}$
```

Comment: Thanks, but no. It wouldn't match partial strings like AB123 that I want to match too.